# Two columns instead of two rows for languages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that selects all rows from my table where the language is spanish or french with a few values in it like this:

**Columns**: *Value1, Value2, LanugageSpecificValue, Language*

The Values are for example:

Row1: xxx, xxx, hola, spanish

Row2: xxx, xxx, bonjour, french

For every Row I get 2 results where the values beside the LanguageSpecificValue are identical, only language is either french or spanish.

Now instead of two rows, I want to get columns like this:

**Columns**: *Value1, Value2, FrenchLanguageSpecificValue, SpanishLanguageSpecificValue*

Row1: xxx, xxx, bonjour, hola

Can anyone help me how to achieve that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please edit your question and add a tag of your database brand (mysql, oracle, mssql, postgresql, etc) that will get more specific attention to your question. For your answer considering only what you provided, search for "rows to columns" or sql pivot there are tons of answers for it. Enjoy your stay here.

Comment: Show us your query.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a key for each sentence so you can link them, in this case I assume value1 is such a key. And then you must have a language that contains all phrases (I suggest English to allow most people to understand, but here I use Spanish). Then you join the values together.

```
select ts.LanugageSpecificValue,
       ts.Language, 
       tf.LanugageSpecificValue, 
       tf.Language 
 from table ts
        left join table tf 
              on ts.value1 = tf.value1 
             and tf.language = 'french'
where ts.langage = 'spanish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing is using `PIVOT` (since you didn't mention I'm assuming `test` as table name)

```
SELECT value1, value2, french, spanish 
FROM 
(
  SELECT value1, value2, word, language
  FROM test 
) as a
PIVOT (
  max(word) FOR language in (french, spanish)
) as piv
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59996/34

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `value1` and `value2` identify each row.  One method is aggregation:

```
select value1, value2,
       max(case when language = 'spanish' then LanugageSpecificValue end) as in_spanish,
       max(case when language = 'french' then LanugageSpecificValue end) as in_french
from t
where language in ('french', 'spanish')
group by value1, value2;
```